# Solr update compressed request

Tags: solr, http-compression

I apologise in advanced if there's already an answer, but I haven't found any...

I'm playing around with a Solr instance, and I was indexing millions of documents, these were split into json files with 500K documents per file, of around 60MB. When compressed the shrinks to a mere 6MB.
So I was wondering if there can be a way to send the compressed file, i.e. 6M instead of 60MB, whereby upon receiving the file, unzip/deflate before processing it.

I've looked around the sol wiki, but solr plugins are "advanced and not recommended"

Comment: Which application container are you using? The bundled jetty? It would be the responsibility of the container to receive the request and deflate it, so you could try `Content-Encoding: gzip` together with `GzipFilter` in jetty.

Comment: If you are using SolrJ to index documents then you can use SolrServer.setAllowCompression method http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer.html#setAllowCompression-boolean-

Comment: @MatsLindh: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried that but I'm getting this error:


`FAILED GzipFilter: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter`

Comment: @sidgate: It's the request that I want to compress

Comment: And how are you creating the request?

Comment: This is how I was to send the data:  
$ch = curl_init('http://myServer:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true&');
curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Content-Encoding:gzip'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, gzencode(json_encode($data), 9));
curl_exec($ch);

Answer (score 0):

After giving it some thought, I concluded that it will be simpler to create a REST endpoint that will handle the compression, and then pass the data locally to Solr, like below:

```
// Grab compressed data and uncompress
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = gzinflate(substr($data, 10, -8));

// Send to Solr
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true&');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type:application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($ch);
```

So I don't need to hack Solr